# Device not found on Mac Os Sierra VM Xcode

Tags: xcode, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am trying to develop iOS apps on windows and have installed mac os on Virtual Box. Xcode is running great but I can't seem to get my device noticed on it... I have mounted the usb device from the menu on virtual box but nothing is working. Please help!